# Accessing the same persistent store from Swift and React Native

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, react-native, realm

We're considering using React Native for one of our Screens - for fun, to check it and to get a better grasp of the possibilities, but even before w start I need some answers, so we're sure React Native and it's environments can meet our requirements.

In this question I'd like to specifically ask about persisting data and accessing it.

In our app we focus on offline experience, as it's one of the most crucial points for us. On iOS we have a couple of possibilities how to achieve this eg. Core Data, Realm... But the thing is if we decide to implement some part of our app as React Native we'd also need these parts to access stored data and even modify it and save to persistent store.
**Can this be achieved? Having one persistent store (SQLite, Realm, something else?) and access it from both Swift code and React Native.**

Comment: I think you'll need to write some wrappers to access native libraries, like CoreData, see some documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html)

Answer (score 6):

This is extremely easy with React Native in both iOS and Android with Native Modules.

You would build a simple native module in Swift/Obj-C and expose your persistent store:

```
//RCTMyDataStore.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface RCTMyDataStore : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

and

```
//  RCTMyDataStore.m

#import "RCTMyDataStore.h"

@implementation RCTMyDataStore {
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(MyDataStore);

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(getMyData,
                 getMyData_resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 getMyData_rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    // get data from my persistent store

    if (success) {
        // convert to RN passable format (NSDictionary or NSArray)

        resolve(myData);
    } else {
        reject(@"404", @"No data", nil);
    }

}


@end
```

In your React Native code:

```
import { 
    NativeModules
} from 'react-native';

const NativeDataStore = NativeModules.MyDataStore; // must match the RCT_EXPORT_MODULE name

NativeDataStore.getMyData()
    .then(data => {
        // do some stuff
    })
```

For more info on Native Modules and Swift support, you can check out the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#exporting-swift